# PHP: how to use getimgasize() after the image is resized using getimageresized after upload?

Tags: php, file-upload, size, return, image-resizing

using the example given at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php ...  how to get image sizes afterward using `getimagesize()` function?

CODE:

```
    <?php

        if(isset($_FILES['images'])){
         //TEST1:
          $img = resize_this_image_now($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']);


         //TEST2:
        $img = resize_this_image_now($_FILES['images']['name']);/// This Drastically failed.

          $new_image = getimagesize($img);

        var_dump($new_image[0]);// I guessed this should have printed out the WIDTH_OF_THE_IMAGE... but, it prints some NON_READABLE stuffs (why?)

    }

// The PHP.NET CODE in a Function

    function resize_this_image_now($filename){
        // File and new size
      //  $filename = 'test.jpg';

        $percent = 0.5;

        // Content type
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        // Get new sizes
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
        $newwidth = $width * $percent;
        $newheight = $height * $percent;

        // Load
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

        // Resize
        imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

        // Output
    return    imagejpeg($thumb);
    }
        ?>
```

All I want *is to get the `Size`* of the `Image`....  also, is it possible to do something like:

`$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] = $the_newly_resized_image_returned_from_the_PHP_dot_NET_code';` .... So that the `['images']['tmp_name']` will now have as source this *new image*??

Any suggestion is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to spend sometime examining you question. What I found out is that, I don't think you'd need to `return` the resized image through `imagejpeg()` the way you did. You might also need to add a `imagedestroy()`, after you call `imagejpeg()` in you `function`, to destroy the temporary memory used.

You need to first **fully Upload the Image** before resizing it. If you'd like, you could send the image in a temporary storage while you do whatever you want to it so that Php does not have to deal with it in a `'tmp_name'` format...Then You can destroy the image later on.

Once the image is fully uploaded, *things become easier.* The codes might look something like:

```
        if(isset($_FILES['images'])){

        //may be some random numbers to accompany it.
        $rand = floor((mt_rand()+rand()+mt_rand())/3);

//Send it to the temporary folder you have had to create.
        if(move_uploaded_file(
                    $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'],'temporary_storage/image_'.$rand.'.jpg')){

        //Then run the `resize` function from here.
        $image_resized = resize_this_image_now('temporary_storage/image_'.$rand.'.jpg');

        //Now You can get the size if you wish.         
        list($width,$height) = getimagesize('temporary_storage/image_'.$rand.'.jpg');   

        // Out put

        echo "W:".$width."<br>H:".$height;

        //After you use it as desired, you can now destroy it using unlink or so.

unlink('temporary_storage/image_'.$rand.'.jpg');

            }else{
    echo "Upload Error goes here";
    }

        }
```

Note this answer is produced after several trials and errors... Please use this strategy wisely.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked, worked,worked... Thank you sooooo much. thoug i did n ot understand the `list` thing. I stack to the array. Like: `$new_image =  getimagesize('temporary_storage/image_'.$rand.'.jpg');` then I called it like: echo `$new_image[0] or [1] or [n]`. It correctly worked. thanks :)

Comment: Cool... Enjoy Programming!